# Haskell Understand Definition of functions

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am not quite able to find a good manual for the following:
If I want to get the definition of a functionality in Haskell, then I am using `:t`
So for example with:

```
:t sqrt
:t (+)
:t truncate
```

I will get:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

I am just not sure how to understand the syntax here, concerning on `=>` and `->`.
I know `::` is about definition the function, but what does the rest mean, concerning the function definition. This will be important to understand functions in general.

Comment: What do you mean with "*what happens afterwards*"?

Comment: Sorry, that was bad written by me, I have corrected this. I just meant what the rest of the list means. Indeed nothing happens because it's just a definition.

Comment: There are countless Haskell tutorials available, and any of them should discuss the type declaration syntax used here. Meanwhile, doing a good and thorough job of answering the question asked here is quite involved and would require covering currying, parametric polymorphism, and ad-hoc polymorphism, each a chapter in its own right. So I vote to close as "too broad" -- but do have a read through some tutorials, which should have the requisite chapters already written.

Comment: Please, please read [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) before asking questions like this. LYAH is a fantastic resource for beginners on the basics of Haskell.

Comment: see https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.3D.3E, https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#-.3E, https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#:: .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know `::` is about definition the function

er, no. `::` means that you're giving a *type signature*, this is not necessarily related to defining the function (though in practice, you *should* give a type signature to every function you write, and even if you don't, the compiler will infer a signature).

```
sqrt :: Double -> Double       -- } type signature

sqrt 0 = 0                     -- ⎫
sqrt 1 = 1                     -- ⎪
sqrt 2 = 1.4  -- should do     -- ⎬ definition
sqrt 4 = 2                     -- ⎪
sqrt _ = error "too hard"      -- ⎭
```

Now – as you've seen these signatures are actually a bit different, not just `Double -> Double`. Specifically, the signature `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` is parsed as

```
sqrt :: forall a .
       (Floating a)
      => (a -> a)
```

which means, this actually works *for all* types `a` (including, but not limited to `Double`), provided they have an `instance Floating`. I.e., the type must support the interface of the [`Floating` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating). For each of these types, the signature will be “type to itself”, i.e.

```
sqrt :: Double -> Double
sqrt :: Complex Double -> Complex Double
sqrt :: Float -> Float
sqrt :: ExactSymbolic -> ExactSymbolic
```

but not e.g. `sqrt :: String -> String`, because `String` is not an instance of `Floating`, nor `Bool -> Char`, which doesn't even match the `a -> a` pattern.

For the other examples it's similar:

- `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` defines an operator that can be used as e.g. `Int -> Int -> Int` or `Rational -> Rational -> Rational`, for all types in the [`Num` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num).
- `truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` can actually convert between two *different* types, for instance `Double -> Int` or `Rational -> Integer`. Requirement is that the argument is in the [`RealFrac` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac), and the result in the [`Integral` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral).

---

How all of these functions are *defined* is another matter – the type signature doesn't tell you that (although for particularly “fundamental” functions, there may actually be only one sensible way to implement it given the type signature). To see how a function is defined, you need to look at the source code. This is normally linked from the Haddock documentation, the little `Source` link right of the signature. For built-in functions like `(+)` on `Double` you won't find any definition though, since these actually just resolve to primops, i.e. hardware processor instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT from the author** *While this explanation is close enough for my base level and the OP base level, this reply is simply wrong, see the comments below.  Please consider other answers.*

A function that take, let's say an `Integer` and returns a `Float` will be written `Integer -> Float`.

However, your function may be more generic.  For instance it can work on any type and return a String.  A dummy name, like `a`, will be used for the input type.  Since the signature is variadic upon `a`, the dependence on the variadic type will be written with `=>`.  Hence the signature would be `a => a -> String`.  If you ever did type theory, this is a Π-type.  Else, think of `=>` as the arrow used to denote a "function of types".  Here that "function of types" takes type `a` and return type `a -> String`, which is a regular function type. (Note that `=>` has lower priority than `->` for putting brackets, because else it makes no sense).

If the type you're depending upon cannot be anytype, but must be a type with some properties, you have to specify its class of properties by giving the class name before the type.  In you question, a type that behaves like a real-valued floating point number is of class `Floating`.

Thus, `Floating a => a -> a` is a dependent function type, depending on `a` which must be of class `Floating`.  Likewise, `(RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` is a double dependent function type, the first dependency must be of class `RealFrac` while the second must be of class `Integral`.

`::` is just the separator between the value (or, in type theory, a "witness") and its type. `truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` just means that `truncate` is of (double-dependent) type `(RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`

Comment: Paragraph two isn't quite right. If there are no constraints on `a`, one simply writes `a -> String`, or you can write `() => a -> String` if you really want to think of the type signature as being constrained with the trivial constraint that is always satisfied.  `a => a -> String` tries to use `a` as both a constraint and an inhabited type, and no types have both of those kinds. Also, `=>` definitely does not denote a Π-type nor a type-level function.

Comment: Okay I've misunderstood `=>` since ever.  The type-level function was only an allegory.  Marking the answer as purely wrong.